# Can't connect Nextetender on Mac OS-X El-Captain

Tags: macos, mac, chmod, osx-el-capitan

I just upgraded from Yosemite to El Captain but I can't connect Dell SonicWALL NetExtender version 7.5.757. I give this log message:

> [general error 463] ERROR: Pppd is not setuid-root and the invoking user is not root. (3)
>
> [general fatal 463] Please delete and reinstall NetExtender, or run chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd an administrator.

then I tried delete and reinstall NetExtender but not working. After I tried `sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd` on terminal but I give this massage:

> chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/sbin/pppd: Operation not permitted

Comment: I have had this problem too. you can try this.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan?answertab=votes#tab-top][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dell SonicWall NextExtender is not compatible with Mac El Captain. There is a software which enables this you can download SonicWALL Mobile Connect, which is released by SonicWALL, from below link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sonicwall-mobile-connect/id822514576?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after upgrading to El Capitan and read the [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested by [giraysam](https://superuser.com/users/293928/giraysam).  Added one more step in order to make the fix to NetExtender:

- Have the NetExtender .dmg install file in a handy location, like your desktop (you will have to reinstall NetExtender)
- Reboot the Mac and hold the Cmnd+R keys to reboot in [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)
- Once in recovery mode, select Utilities -> Terminal from the menu bar
- Execute the following command:  csrutil disable
- Reboot the Mac (do not hold any keys)
- Open the terminal window and execute the following command:  chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd
- Reinstall the NetExtender program
- Connect to your VPN with the NetExtender program - It should connect successfully
- Log off your VPN and reboot your Mac. Hold the Cmnd+R keys to reboot in recovery mode
- Once in recovery mode, select Utilities -> Terminal from the menu bar
- Execute the following command:  csrutil enable
- Reboot the Mac (do not hold any keys)

That worked for me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: FYI: csrutil command is used to configure Mac's "System Integrity Protection", introduced in OS X 10.11 El Capitan.  More can be seen in  [Mac Developer LIbrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html)